# What Technic set should I get for general Technic MOC?

Tags: technic, sets, moc

I want to do some small machines in [these books](https://www.nostarch.com/technic), But the sets [recommended by the author](http://www.isogawastudio.co.jp/legostudio/others/ideabook_partslist.html) are super expensive (set 8043 8053).

> LEGO Technic Sets I Recommend (December, 2010)
>   Honestly, it is hard to find LEGO Technic sets which include a good variety of parts. Most include the parts you’ll need in order to make a particular model, like a car or helicopter. In addition, the sets available in the USA differ from those in Japan, where I live. Of the sets sold in the USA, I think the best set is #8043 (Motorized Excavator) ....

What are today's "equivalent version" of 8043 and 8053?

Comment: The 42055 Excavator has a ton of parts and since it is still being sold by The LEGO Group itself they should be relatively cheap compared to discontinued sets that are only sold in the secondary market.

Comment: Any large Technic set on shop.lego.com, provided it has a batterybox and a motor (or more) should typically fit the bill.

Comment: @chicks thanks, in fact I got the exact model you recommended, but too few gears.

Comment: You could go to ebay and buy a general lot of pieces, or pick up a specialist page of shop owners that can supply a range of mixed pieces set out on a page of one colour at a time, often they have 180 pieces at a time per lot Or you could go for a kilo lot of pieces- but the postage will be quite high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really buy the Lego Technic Bucket Wheel Excavator. It's a great price for the parts and has a very wide variety of parts: banana gears to Power Functions Elements.